# Which API function should be used to update data of certain data points in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to update the historical data of certain data points in the Apache IoTDB, and other data points do not have data to update. Which API function should I use in IoTDB to do that, and how can I update these time series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write data to with the same timestamp, this means a data update to Apache IoTDB. Whatever which API function you use, as long as the `insert` operation is made to the same timestamp, the data of this timestamp will be updated.